# How setup CActiveDataProvider in YII for many to many plus a third relationship

Tags: php, yii, many-to-many, dataprovider, cactivedataprovider

I have an AR object "league".

league is many to many to player via league_has_player lt (which has lt.leauge_id and lt.player_id.
I have team is many to many to player via team_has_player 
A third relation is team which is many to one to league (team has team.league_id)

I want all the players who are not on a team in the league.

In trying to setup my dataProvider for a GridView, I have tried this condition:

```
public function searchPlayerByLeagueNotOnTeam()
{    
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->order = 't.last_name ASC';
    $criteria->join = ', team ,player';
    $criteria->condition = 'player.id not in '
                    . '(select team_has_player.player_id '
                    . 'from team_has_player)';

    return new CActiveDataProvider('player', array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

But I get all the players multiple times.